# What adapter do I need to fit a Vivitar lens to a Canon 4000D?

Tags: lens, canon, t-mount

I’m looking for an adapter that will fit a Vivitar F/8.0 multi coated telephoto lens to my Canon EOS 4000D.

Comment: There are practically all kinds of adapters available for Canon cameras in all major photo gear shops. You are looking to adapt your lens' mount to EF mount (this is what your camera has). If you want to know what mount your lens has you need to add photos of it including the mount.

Comment: As always with this kind of question, please see: [Can I use lens brand X on interchangeable lens camera brand Y?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/62000)

Answer (score 2):

All of the Vivitar fixed aperture f/8 lenses I am aware of are T-mount; like the 500/8 mirror lens and the 500/8 telephoto lens.

You would need a T-mount to EOS (EF-S) adaptor for those kind of lenses. They are readily available and quite inexpensive.

Comment: Good answer. One minor correction: The Vivitar 500mm f/8 telephoto “Preset” lens has multiple apertures. (8,11,16,22,32)